# Cannot redeclare class Cake\ORM\Behavior\ in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I created `src/Model/Behavior/ModernTreeBehavior.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Cake\ORM\Behavior;

use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\Behavior;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use RuntimeException;

class ModernTreeBehavior extends Behavior
{

    /**
     * Cached copy of the first column in a table's primary key.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_primaryKey;

    /**
     * Default config
     *
     * These are merged with user-provided configuration when the behavior is used.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_defaultConfig = [
        'implementedFinders' => [
            'children' => 'findChildren',
            'treeList' => 'findTreeList'
        ],
        'implementedMethods' => [
            'childCount' => 'childCount',
            'getLevel' => 'getLevel'
        ],
        'parent' => 'parent_id',
        'path' => 'path',
        'scope' => null,
        'level' => null
    ];

    public function getLevel($entity)
    {
        $primaryKey = $this->_getPrimaryKey();
        $id = $entity;
        if ($entity instanceof EntityInterface) {
            $id = $entity->get($primaryKey);
        }
        $config = $this->config();
        $entity = $this->_table->find('all')
            ->select([$config['path']])
            ->where([$primaryKey => $id])
            ->first();

        if ($entity === null) {
            return false;
        }

        return substr_count($entity[$config['path']], '-') + 1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a single string value representing the primary key of the attached table
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getPrimaryKey()
    {
        if (!$this->_primaryKey) {
            $this->_primaryKey = (array)$this->_table->primaryKey();
            $this->_primaryKey = $this->_primaryKey[0];
        }
        return $this->_primaryKey;
    }
}
```

I used `$this->addBehavior('ModernTree');` in CommentTables.php

and I got error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Cake\ORM\Behavior\ModernTreeBehavior in .../src/Model/Behavior/ModernTreeBehavior.php on line 0`

But if I paste `/src/Model/Behavior/ModernTreeBehavior.php` into built-in file `TreeBehavior.php` and load TreeBehavior.php, everything so goods.

Can you tell me the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The namespace declaration of your class is wrong, it should be:

```
namespace App\Model\Behavior;
```